# Get data sub collection and grouping by parent collection firebase angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying show array data from collection and filter it by sub collection data.

Here is the **collection**

- User

  - id
  - name

Here for the **sub-collection**

- Chat

  - idUser
  - message
  - date
  - read

How to list and grouping all user with date from subcollection (chat).
The result array like this

- id
- name
- message (last message)
- read
- date (last chat time)

do i need create new collection for store all data?

I have tring with this code.
Can not show the data when looping it

```
getChats() {
let users: any = [];

return this.chatService.getUsers().pipe(
  switchMap((res: any) => {
    users = res;
    return this.firestore
      .collection('user')
      .doc(this.idUser)
      .collection('chat', (ref) => ref.orderBy('date'))
      .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }) as Observable<Message[]>;
  }),
  map((messages) => {
    for (let m of messages) {
      m.name = this.getUserForMsg(m.id, users);
      m.read = this.idUser === m.dc001frommsg;
    }
    return messages;
  })
);
```

}

```
(await this.getChats()).subscribe((data) => {
  this.listChat = data;
}))
```

in Html

```
<ul *ngFor="let user of listChats">
   <li (click)="detail(user)"> {{ user.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello,

Please could you share more information about this issue? (you mention that you can not show the data when looping it, have you tried to get to this data from another approach?) Also, what are you getting when you are looping the data (null data?)?

Comment: I don't know how to group the sub collection with his parent?
I want to show all name with his message and date chat. Thank you.

Comment: I think it also could be useful to use a [collectionGroup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) in order to solve this issue. as this will query will execute for all the Chats subcollection (and you can limit it with where so that you only get specific data in a single consult).